# Store included file output into variable

Tags: java, jstl

I am currently working on a project that uses JSP however we stay away from using JSTL and use Java instead.

I know with JSTL we can use

```
<c:set var="body">
<jsp:include page="...jsp"/>
</c:set>

<c:out value="${body}"/>
```

However we are trying to stay away from this and use a pure Java implementation.

Is there anyway we can flush the JspWriter (out), include the file on the pageContext and then store the content included into a variable?

Coming from a PHP background, I know we can use ob_start etc, so was hoping we could do the same in Java?

Any idea's would be welcomed.

Many thanks

Gavin

Answer (score 0):

This is an unusual question. Most of the time we are trying to get rid of java code in our JSPs. But, if you don't really want to use JSTL, then you can try this code.

```
<%@ page import="java.net.*,java.io.*"  %>
<%
   StringBuffer requestURL = request.getRequestURL();
   String servletPath = request.getServletPath();
   String contextURL = requestURL.substring(0, requestURL.indexOf(servletPath) + 1);
   URL url = new URL(contextURL + "otherPage.jsp");
   URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
   String inputLine;
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)sb.append(inputLine);
   in.close();
   pageContext.setAttribute("otherPage", sb);
%>
${otherPage}
```